# How to call another function in go?

Tags: go

i want to call GetUsers from Insert function, but i don't know.

```
func GetUsers(c echo.Context) error{
  result := models.GetUsers()
  return c.Render(http.StatusOK, "users.html", result)
}

func Insert(c echo.Context) error{
  models.Insert()
  return c.GetUsers()
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call it from `Insert` simply using `GetUsers`.

```
func Insert(c echo.Context) error{
    models.Insert()
    return GetUsers(c)
}
```

---

The syntax you used, `c.GetUsers()` requires `GetUsers` to be a method declared with `Context` as its receiver type—in the `echo` package—a like so:

```
// package echo
func (c Context) GetUsers() error {
    …
}

// package other
func Insert(c echo.Context) error{
    models.Insert()
    return c.GetUsers()
}
```

But I am going to assume this is not what you want, since a `Context` idiomatically should not contain users.

Comment: Note that in Go it's not possible to declare methods on imported types, you can declare methods on a type only in the same package in which the type is declared. This `func (c echo.Context) GetUsers() error` will never even compile.